# Trouble with pip in Mountain Lion

Tags: python, path, osx-mountain-lion, pip, easy-install

I'm having trouble running pip in Mountain Lion.  I was under the impression that it should come preinstalled with Python (which is working), but trying to run any pip command just presents me with the following:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I've tried

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

but get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 10, in
>
> load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r88846', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 347, in load_entry_point
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2516, in load_entry_point
>
> ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found

I've also tried using get-pip.py, as suggested at http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html, but this gives me a whole slew of errors.

Installing from source seems to work, but pip is still not found

I have a feeling there might be something wrong with my path:

```
~/.bin/:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This might be a problem stemming from the fact that Apple has its own Python distribution. I maintain my own installation of Python, separate from the one that came with the OS. There are several tools that let you download and build Python (`brew`, `macports`) locally. If you use Home Brew to install Python, you get `pip` and `easy_install` for free.

Comment: if you install successfully pip from source, it should be there: did you try to see if it has been installed as pip-2.7 ?